# form values don't pass after I put script links on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a multi-step form for capturing leads and generating potential client estimates. I modified a framework that I found elsewhere on the web. The form looks and works beautifully now, but I need to pass the values from the form through PHP to email. I'm not a stranger to this process, but I believe that something in the Javascript required to make the form beautiful and interactive is voiding the values that should be passing from the form to the email.

What I have done to test (trust me, I hate to bother people, but this is driving me nuts):

I eliminated the fieldsets and any other extra form-formatting, all links to CSS and Javascript. I tested the form and it worked as expected. I took the name in the name="name" field and emailed it to me no problems.

I systematically reconstructed the form until it was complete with fieldsets and CSS. I tested at every step and the form continued to pass the name into the email.

Finally, I added the javascript used for transitions and calculations to the bottom of the page and it no longer performs as expected. It triggers the PHP, but it doesn't redirect as I want it to. and it sends the labels in the email, but doesn't pass the values from the form. If I move the Javascript links to the head, the transitions don't occur making it impossible to navigate to the submit button. Any clues?

Here is the link to the form: http://bigislandwebsitedesign.com/test_form.html

You can follow the links to the various scripts from the source.

Comment: This sounds like more of a JavaScript/HTML issue to me.  The back-end (PHP) seems to be doing its job correctly.

Comment: There are JS errors on the page, which is probably causing problems.  Also, you might consider event listeners as opposed to inline JS.

Comment: I am trying to use Firefox to find the errors, but I am only finding 2 warnings that seem to be, from what I've researched, a Firefox bug. I would like to learn how to implement event listeners, but for now, I would really love to know what [most likely] tiny, little thing is preventing this from executing properly.

Comment: show code, show debugging tries, show errors

Comment: [link](http://bigislandwebsitedesign.com/test_form.html)
You can see all the code from the links. Too long to paste in here.

Comment: There are no errors, only 2 warnings that read:
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1
Error: http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one